# SshClient.Connect() blocked indefinitely while trying to connect with a host that does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, ssh.net

I am using Renci.SshNet (RuntimeVersion: 2.0.50727) to connect ssh enabled linux machines, it is working properly for the hosts that are available in the network but whenever I am trying to connect to any hosts that are not in the network it seems to stuck at the line `SshClient.Connect()`

I am thinking of an workaround like pinging the device before connecting to it but not sure how reliable it will be.

Comment: Pinging the device won't always work, it may be configured to not respond to pings

Answer (score 1):

The [`ConnectionInfo`](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/ConnectionInfo.cs) has a `Timeout` property that you can set. It defaults to 30 seconds so I'd recommend lowering it to something more tolerable for your environment such as 5 seconds.

If you are connecting using host names you could also optionally take on the task of resolving those to IP addresses using [`Dns.GetHostEntry()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var entries = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);
if( entries.AddressList.Length > 0 )
{
    //Optionally do some checking with AddressFamily if you have v4/v6 issues
    var ip = entries.AddressList[0];
}
```

If you wanted to maker a "pinger" you could just use [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/115ytk56(v=vs.110).aspx) to try to bind to the host and port but since that's essentially what the `SshClient` is doing anyway I think it would be overkill.

Comment: Even after setting timeout it is not properly exiting I have waited for so long it seems stuck, probably a bug I guess

Comment: Are you connecting to an IP or a host name?